# Create an empty SQLAlchemy query as a base for searching a model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to search a model based on multiple criteria.  The user enters a search term and selects which fields to search.  If no fields are selected, I want to return an empty result.  How do I create an empty query object?  Or is there a better way to construct this?

```
results = *an empty query object*

if nameChecked:
    nameResults = System.query.filter(System.system_name.contains(searchTag))
    results = results.union(nameResults)

if descriptionChecked:
    descriptionResults = System.query.filter(System.system_description.contains(searchTag))
    results = results.union(descriptionResults)

if tagsChecked:
    tagsResults = System.query.filter(System.system_tags.contains(searchTag))
    results = results.union(tagsResults)
```

Comment: Found the answer. For anybody interested, Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't support an empty query object but an easy solution is: `results = System.query.filter(0==1)`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than getting a separate checked value for each field, use multiple checkboxes with different values but the same name to get a list of fields to filter.

Check if no fields were selected and if so return an empty list.  Otherwise, collect a list of filters and `or_` them together.  `union` is not necessary in this case.

```html
<form>
    <input name="q">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="name">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="description">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="tags">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% if results %}
    output the results
{% endif %}
```

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    value = request.args['q']
    fields = set(request.args.getlist('field'))

    if not fields:
        return render_template('search.html', results=[])

    filters = []

    if 'name' in fields:
        filters.append(System.name.contains(value))

    if 'description' in fields:
        filters.append(System.description.contains(value))

    if 'tags' in fields:
        filters.append(System.tags.contains(value))

    results = System.query.filter(db.or_(*filters)).all()
    return render_template('search.html', results=results)
```

You could get clever with a dictionary and compact the filters, but it's probably less efficient.

```
    results = System.query.filter(db.or_(*(value for key, value in {
        'name': System.name.contains(value),
        'description': System.description.contains(value),
        'tags': System.tags.contains(value)
    }.items() if key in fields))).all() if fields else []
```

If you really need an empty query as opposed to an empty result, you can use `System.query.filter(False)`.  This is of limited use because you can't do anything with the query afterwards, any filters will be ignored.